# Docker | Ubuntu | Запрет монтирования локальных каталогов

Tags: linux, docker

При запуске контейнера, пользователь может монтировать каталог с флагом:

```
-v /hostdir/:/contdir/
```

Можно ли это как-нибудь запретить?
На уровне демона докера, чтобы не прописывать профайлы каждого контейнера в `apparmor`?

Comment: Так же, не рассматриваю вариант с seccomp. Пользователь сможет запустить контейнер без конфига по ограничению команд

Comment: докер доступен в сорцах - скачайте и пересоберите под себя

Comment: Увы, не обладаю навыками программирования, ищу костыль или решение для ограничения привилегий при запуске/управлении

Comment: тогда создайте алиас, который, и проверит ключ. Да, умный пользователь всегда обойдет,а  обычный нет

Comment: Какой именно алиас имеется ввиду?

Comment: пишите баш скрипт, который будет просто пробрасывать параметры докеру, но фильтровать "ненужные". И добавляете имя через alias в .bash_rc/.bash_profile.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_authorization/#api-schema-and-implementation там какието плагины есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может это не то что вы хотите, но попробую ответить.

Запретить монтировать в докер можно, используя костыли: к примеру разрешить пользователям только выполнение определенных по маске команд для запуска контейнеров.

Но если проблема конкретно в доступе из-под контейнера в файловую систему рут-хоста, то у разработиков docker есть такой вариант защиты: включить [user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/). Как это работает:

1. добавляем пользователя

   `$ sudo adduser dockremap`
2. Установим для него subiud и subgid

   `$ sudo sh -c 'echo dockremap:500000:65536 > /etc/subuid'
   $ sudo sh -c 'echo dockremap:500000:65536 > /etc/subgid'`
3. Добавляем параметр "userns-remap" для этого создадим/изменим файл (/etc/docker/daemon.json) добавив параметр

   `{
      "userns-remap": "default"
   }`
4. перезапускаем демона - `/etc/init.d/docker restart`

После этих манипуляций проброшенный внутрь контейнера каталог не может быть изменен пользователями с одинаковыми uid:gid внутри котейнера, так как контейнер выполняется в другом (пользовательском) пространстве имен.

Comment: Не помогло увы :(

Comment: Хотя нет, поторопился - помогло! Спасибо